Is it necessary to iterate the simulated annealing algorithm so many times in a production scenario?
I have recently been working on coding a solution for a assembly line balancing problem. My approach is to first use a greedy algorithm to generate an initial feasible solution, and then apply simulated annealing to optimize it. During the cooling process of the simulated annealing algorithm, I use simple random generation to create neighboring solutions and attempt to find the best one among them.
One issue I've noticed is that in most test cases, even before the algorithm converges (i.e., reaches the termination temperature), it can already find a very good solution, which often turns out to be the historically optimal solution after convergence. I'm wondering whether I really need to set such a high number of iterations for my program as recommended by literature and some algorithm repositories (for example, currently my initial temperature is 1e+5, termination temperature is 1e-5, alpha is 0.98, and the number of iterations per temperature step is 30, meaning the total number of iterations would be around 34,200), or if I could still find a suitable solution with fewer iterations?
I am wondering if, in your past production work, you would consider reducing the number of computations to decrease the time and other burdens, or if you strictly follow the standards set by the literature? Can I stop the computation before the curve converges?

Generally, given that you are using a heuristic for computing a solution to a practical problem, you are not obliged to do anything in particular.
Your goal is presumably to obtain a good (enough) solution, and it seems you can achieve this goal with fewer iterations than you expected from the theory of simulated annealing. So, you should stop when you are happy with solution quality.
You should note that the simulated annealing algorithm only asymptotically converges to an optimal solution under very specific assumption about neighbourhood structure - and if these are not satisfied, you are not guaranteed an optimal solution no matter for how long you run your algorithm.
In Handbook of Metaheuristics, chapter 2, there is convergence proof that emphasises the assumptions for convergence. The book is freely available if you have an institution login (at least from my institution).

My 2 cents will be if heuristics like SA are converging to optima pretty faster than you think then may be there's an exact solution using LP or MILP solving in polynomial time. May explore that also.

But I'm not actually sure that those historically optimal solutions I've found are globally optimal - I haven't formulated an exact model for this problem to verify that, and usually I just look at whether the fitness value is lower than my initial solution to determine that. I'll take your suggestion into consideration for subsequent development though, thx for suggestion!
